# How to select dependant on another value being within a range for a certain timerange

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables one that reads voltage and one that reads current. The entries in these tables represent a change, therefore a specific value is constant until the next row.

I need to collect a voltage reading ONLY when the current has been between a certain range for at least 8 seconds.

The actual data sets are very very large and so far I have been using a left join on the condition where timestamps match and the timestamp_diff is less than 8. This is obviously massively inefficient and takes over an hour to complete.

`anti_current_data` contains all rows where the current is outside of the desired values.

```
LEFT JOIN anti_current_data ON
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(voltage_data.timestamp, anti_current_data.timestamp, SECOND) > -8 
    AND TIMESTAMP_DIFF(voltage_data.timestamp, anti_current_data.timestamp, SECOND) < 0
```

How could I approach this scenario more effectively?

Example:

in these tables, if the current is positive for 8+ seconds, I can use the final row and collect the voltage as 46v.

| timestamp | current |
| --- | --- |
| 15/07/2022 09:05:22 | -2 |
| 15/07/2022 09:05:42 | -1 |
| 15/07/2022 09:06:04 | 6 |
| 15/07/2022 09:06:16 | 2 |

| timestamp | voltage |
| --- | --- |
| 15/07/2022 09:05:22 | 42 |
| 15/07/2022 09:05:42 | 44 |
| 15/07/2022 09:06:04 | 48 |
| 15/07/2022 09:06:16 | 46 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem you are facing is needing to analyze previous records.  To achieve this you can use a [LAG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#lag) function as shown below.  This will allow you to set parameters in a Qualify clause when certain conditions are met like the difference between the previous and current time.

With the sample data you provided try the following:

```
select
  acd.timestamp,
  acd.`current`,
  vd.voltage,
  datetime_diff(acd.timestamp, lag(acd.timestamp) over (timestamp_window), SECOND) as s_diff,
  lag(acd.`current`) over (timestamp_window) previous_current
from anti_current_data acd
join voltage_data vd
 on acd.timestamp = vd.timestamp
qualify previous_current > 0
  and s_diff >=8
window timestamp_window as (order by acd.timestamp)
```

It produces the following results:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about likes this?

voltage_data.timestamp between (anti_current_data.timestamp - 8s) and anti_current_data.timestamp

```sql
SELECT
  TIMESTAMP("2008-12-25 15:30:00+00") AS original,
  TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP "2008-12-25 15:30:00+00", INTERVAL -8 SECOND ) AS earlier;
```

Comment: I'm not sure that answers my question, thank you regardless.